# Delete rest of string after a certain character

Tags: ios, swift3

I wanted to know how would you delete the rest of a string after a certain character. I know how to replace the occurrences of a string but don't know how would you delete the rest of the string after a certain character. Example

```
let names = ["Tommy-normal", "Bob-fat", "Jack-skinny", "Rob-obese"]
for x in names {
print(x.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " "))
```

}

Instead I would like to just delete the rest of the string that comes after ***-*** so it will just print out ***Tommy***, ***Bob***, ***Jack*** and ***Rob***.

Would appreciate any Help.

Comment: Find the index of that character, take the prefix up to that index.

Comment: Would really appreciate it if you can provide sample code. Doing it your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is `map` with a closure

```
var names = ["Tommy-normal", "Bob-fat", "Jack-skinny", "Rob-obese"]

names = names.map { string -> String in
    if let range = string.range(of: "-") {
        return string.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
    }
    return string
}
```

Or

```
names = names.map { string -> String in
    if let index = string.characters.index(of: "-") {
        return string.substring(to: index)
    }
    return string
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vadian, it works. Would you happen to know how to do it the way Sulthan provided. Where you find the index of that character, take the prefix up to that index

Comment: That (the second example) is actually the way Sulthan suggested.

Comment: Ah okay thank you Vadian. Now I know two ways to do it. :)

Comment: Excellent answer. I was in the process of composing an answer when I saw this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could split into an array and take the first element as below:

```
var names = ["Tommy-normal", "Bob-fat", "Jack-skinny", "Rob-obese"]

for name in names {
let arr =  name.components(separatedBy: "-")
        print(arr[0])
}
```

**Prints:**

Tommy

Bob

Jack

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
let names = ["Tommy-normal", "Bob-fat", "David", "Jack-skinny", "Rob-obese"];

for (let name of names) {

    let index = name.indexOf("-");

    if (index >= 0) name = name.substring(0, index);

    console.log(name);
}
```

Be careful when the word starts with "-".

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Sulthan's suggestion (vadian's 2nd approach) but want to make it slightly more general-purpose you could create a function that extracts the first part of a string up to a delimiter, and then use that:

```
func firstPart(of aString: String, separator: String) -> String {
  if let range = aString.range(of: separator) {
    return aString.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
  }
  return aString
}



let names = ["Tommy", "Bob-fat", "Jack-skinny", "Rob-obese"]
let firstParts: [String] = names.map {
  firstPart(of: $0, separator: "-")
}
print("firstParts = \(firstParts)")
```

That gives the result:

```
firstParts = ["Tommy", "Bob", "Jack", "Rob"]
```

You could also write code that maps your original array into tuples with a name part and a "morphology" part:

```
let tuples = names
  .map{$0.components(separatedBy: "-")}
  .map{(name:$0[0], morphology: $0.count > 1 ? $0[1] : "unkown morphology")}

tuples.forEach{ print($0.name + " is " + $0.morphology) }
```

With my version of your data, where I deleted the "-normal" part of "Tommy-normal", to make sure the code handled missing suffixes, I get:

```
Tommy is unkown morphology
Bob is fat
Jack is skinny
Rob is obese
```